# Query on Model in a For Loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Is there a way to query in my Model in a For loop, similar to how it's done in a foreach?
ex:

```cs
foreach (var item in Model.Where(x => x.product == product))
```

Comment: you want to replace `foreach` loop with `for` loop?

Comment: Here is a full description of the issue I am facing. My understanding is that one way to solve the issue is to adapt my current code to use a for loop instead of a foreach. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56799256/any-way-to-bind-form-data-with-ef-in-a-foreach?noredirect=1#comment100157474_56799256

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
@{var items = Model.Where(x => x.product == product).ToList();}
@for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
{
... stuff with items[i] ...
}
```

The ToList() is to enumerate items so you can loop through with an index.

Comment: This is not exactly the same. With foreach you going through `Model` only once, but with your code you are going through twice.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for equivalent of `foreach (var item in Model.Where(x => x.product == product))` here you go:

```
var index = 0; // in case you need an index in your loop
for (var e = Model.Where(x => x.product == product).GetEnumerator(); e.MoveNext(); index++)
{
    var item = e.Current;

    // rest of your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your point is to obtain the index, use the `Select` overload with index

```
foreach(var (item, index) in Model.Where(x => x.product == product).Select((a, b) => (a, b)))
{
    // statements
}
```

If you must use the form of `for`

```
for(var (enumerator, index) = (Model.Where(x => x.product == product).GetEnumerator(), 0); enumerator.MoveNext(); index++)
{
    // statements
}
```

Comment: why do you think they need `index`? Also you should note that you need C# v7.0 (VS 2017 at least) to work with Tuples in this way.

Comment: @vasily.sib The op refuses to use `ToList` which means caching as a mutable collection with random access, so `index` would be the only purpose of using `for` loop. And all that we need to make it work is to use the latest roslyn to compile it , targeting a .NET implementation with tuple support or  a reference to `System.ValueTuple` package. VS is irrelated.

Comment: op actualy never tells anything, but ok, I get your point. What about roslyn - what I mean is that you can mention this in your answer. Without `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` nuget package, VS 2015 (for example) can't compile this.

Comment: you may also just define `var index = 0;` outside of your loop and get rid of tuples

Comment: I don't know what op asks for, for we cannot use `foreach`. Is it that this must be done within a `for` loop? Then there would be no definition outside of the loop. Since roslyn is not a Visual Studio built-in, we could use standalone .NET Core SDK or Mono SDK without Visual Studio.